# Meteor; How to set up one time variables for new users?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'd like to set certain variables upon first login, and I am using an external API. e.g., upon *only* first login, we create var score 0, and a bunch of different variables tied to the profile.

```
Accounts.onLogin(function() {
    // To retrieve more details about user
    var steamApiKey = ("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"); //Steam API KEY
    var steam64Id = Meteor.user().profile.id; //User's Steam 64 ID
    var result = Meteor.http.get('http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=' + steamApiKey + '&steamids=' + steam64Id);
            
    Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), // Steam Nickname
        { $set: { 'profile.personaname': result.data.response.players[0].personaname}}
        );
    Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), // Steam Avatar
        { $set: { 'profile.steamAvatar': result.data.response.players[0].avatarmedium}}
        );
    Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(),
        { $set: { 'profile.score': "0"}}
        );
});
```

I only have this. Why will it always update to 0 everytime I log in even though I manually updated score to 100?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking whether the fields created at first login already exist or not.

```
Accounts.onLogin(function() {
    let user = Meteor.user();
    if (user.profile.hasOwnProperty("personaname")) return;

    // To retrieve more details about user
    var steamApiKey = ("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"); //Steam API KEY
    // ...and so on.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All I saw is one time variable so regardless of what your trying to do ima put my 2 cents in about localStorage so here goes

```js
var score = 0;

function Start(){
  //if localStorage does not have key
  if(!localStorage.hasKey("score")){
    localStorage.setItem("score",0);
  }
}
```

so lets talk about some loading and saving functions

```js
var score = 0;

function Start(){
  Load();
}

function Save(){
  localStorage.setItem("score",score);
}

function Load(){
  var score_save = localStorage.getItem("score") || "0";
  
  score = parseInt(score_save);
}

//Once everything is initialized start
Start();

//Save every second
setInterval(Save,1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, so I created one collection called "userprofile". The _id of the document in "userprofile" collection will be same as user collection _id. In this way we create reference inside userprofile document.

```
 Suppose user collection _id ='1234' then we will save userprofile document with _id:'1234'

'findUser':function() {


// Make sure the user is logged in before inserting a task
if (! this.userId) {
  throw new Meteor.Error('not-authorized');
}

 var userProfile = userprofile.findOne(
 { _id: this.userId});

 if(userProfile===null ||userProfile===undefined) {
    userprofile.insert({_id:this.userId});
}
});
```